# Ubuntu 22 - After updated, i can't find my proxy when i'm in vpn

Tags: vpn, proxy, connection

I was with Ubuntu 20 and i updated to Ubuntu 22. After it, i can't connect with internal sites into vpn that need a proxy configured. It's not my internet connection because in another notebook, it's works well.

Comment: Are you sure you're asking about a Ubuntu 20 upgrade to 22, as no user applications change during that upgrade unlike for example a 20.04 upgrade to 22.04 which is very different!  Ubuntu releases using the *year* format are different products to the *year.month* with differences which is why the format of release differs.  No change should occur on a 20 system upgraded to 22 as only the base system changed

Comment: My notebook is a Dell with dual boot (win + ubuntu). After the update, even the proxy on Windows stopped working. So I think the update messed something up.

Comment: When you upgrade a Ubuntu Core 20 system to Ubuntu Core 22, no user-applications change which is a benefit of *snap* packages ie. the same apps that worked on Ubuntu Core 16 work on Ubuntu Core 22 or releases in between.  The *year* (16, 18, 20 & 22) systems differ to the *year.month* products (ie. 16.04, 18.04, 20.04. 22.04) where *deb* packages change during the *release-upgrade* process. My comment was based on a suspicion that you weren't use 20 (upgrading to 22), but instead were on a different 20.04 system (upgrading to 22.04). A Ubuntu upgrade won't impact windows so I'd look at network

Comment: That's right! I was on version 20.04 and I updated to 22. I am using FortiClient VPN and I set the proxy in firefox only. Before the update it worked fine, then not anymore. Maybe the problem is in the forticlient version. I will check. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ubuntu Core 20 can upgrade to Ubuntu Core 22; you cannot upgrade a Ubuntu 20.04 system to a 22 system; as 20.04 can only upgrade to a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system.  The 22 & 22.04 products are different  (eg. there is no `apt` command in 22 (it's *snap* only), but there is an `apt` command in 22.04 etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you solve it? I meet the same problem. I was ubuntu20.04LTS and I upgrade it to ubuntu22.04LTS now. Then, I cannot use trojan proxy while it worked fine before.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. We generally only reply to questions with an answer if we have an answer for the question - asking other questions or using the answer section for things other than answers goes against our Q&A format. Thank you for joining, and feel free to post non-duplicate questions if you need help! If you run into a question you know the answer to, we'd also love to know the answer to it.